# For any $m \times n$ matrix $A$, the matrices $A^{t}A$ and $AA^{t}$ are positive semi- definite.

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

> For any $m \times n$ matrix $A$, then $A^{t}A$ and $AA^{t}$ are
>   positive semi-definite.

How do I prove the theorem using the definition of positive semi-definiteness? I know the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix), but the definition is not helping me. Please give me hints. How do I work out the given problem?

Comment: $$(AA^{t}x, x)=(A^{t}x, A^{t}x) $$

Comment: Hint: Use the definition and the fact $(AB)^t=B^tA^t.$

Comment: To add to Verduss, Hint 2 : A vector can also be seen as a matrix ($n \times 1$ or $1 \times n$)

Comment: Oh, and one should add: The result as stated is not true. I guess you meant positive semidefinite? (Don't know, if some authors mean that by saying positive definite)

Comment: $A=(0)∈ℝ^{1×1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated the result is not true as you can see by taking the null matrix. But for all matrices $A$ the products $AA^t$ and $A^tA$ are positive *semidefinite*.

Hint: Just use the definition and use the fact that $(AB)^t=B^tA^t$ and that vectors can be seen as matrices, too.

Comment: I have edited. I didn't think about the inner product definition. Now I am able to work out.

Answer (score 0):

Because, since
$$
0 < {\bf x}^T {\bf x} = {\bf x} \cdot {\bf x} = \left| {\bf x} \right|^{\,2} \quad \left| {\,{\bf 0} \ne \forall {\bf x}} \right.
$$

Then, assuming that the null-space of $\bf A$ is empty,
$$
{\bf y} = {\bf A}\,{\bf x}\quad |\;\bf 0 \ne \bf x \; \to \;\bf 0 \ne \bf y \quad\quad 0 < \left| y \right|^{\,2}  = {\bf x}^T {\bf A}^T {\bf Ax}\quad \left| \matrix{
  \,{\bf 0} \ne \forall {\bf x} \hfill \cr 
  \,{\bf 0} \ne \forall {\bf A} \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
which is the definition of *Positive Definite*

Comment: Just a remark on LaTeX formatting: Using \boldsymbol{} is looking better for vectors and matrices.

Comment: One should add that you assume that the kernel of A is trivial.

Comment: @Verdruss: I understand that you mean that the nullspace of $\bf A$ should be empty: I corrected in this sense, thanks for signalling.

Comment: @MrYouMath: did not know about that, thanks, I will keep it present in future.