# Find positive eigenvalue from a symmtric matrix without computing

Tags: linear-algebra

The question Im encounter is given a matrix:

$$ A^TA = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 & -4\\
-2 & 4 & 8\\
-4 & 8 & 42
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I need to tell how many eigenvalues of given matrix is positive? zero or negative.
From this matrix I can find two information

1. the rank is 2
2. it's symmetric matrix

The answer for this question is 2 positive e-values because rank=2 ,1 zero e-value because it's singular.

**But I don't understand why rank and e-value related? How to know it's singular without compute determinate.**

And I also want to know does $A^TA$ has same eigenvector as $A$?

Comment: This problem appears in mit 18.06 exam 3

Comment: It is not clear in your post whether you see why the rank is $2$: you write "the rank is $2$" and next "How to know it's singular [...]?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A positive semi-definite matrix is diagonalizable and its eigenvalues are non-negative, hence its rank equals its number of positive eigenvalues.

Details of the "hence": since [Similar Matrices have the same rank](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3171621/similar-matrices-have-the-same-rank), if $B=PDP^{-1}$ with $D=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_r,0,\dots,0)$ and $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_r\ne0$, then $\operatorname{rank}(B)=\operatorname{rank}(D)=r$.

Comment: And your $A$ may have no eigenvector,   but I think that additional question should have been posted separatly.

Comment: How do you know it's positive semi-definite without knowing all e-values? The defination is all e-value >= 0 , it's positive semi-def.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2450437/for-any-m-times-n-matrix-a-the-matrices-ata-and-aat-are-positive

Comment: where can I find the proof of your answer?

Comment: Of which part? 1. the fact that $A^TA$ is positive semi-definite? (with which definition?), or 2. that a real symmetric matrix is diagonalizable? or 3. that the eigenvalues of a positive semi-definite matrix (with which definition) are non-negative? or 4. that this entails that the rank is number of positive eigenvalues? or 5. something else?

Comment: #4 , why rank=num of positive e-value? thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Sylvester's Law of Inertia says two positive eigenvalues  and a single zero eigenvalue.

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
4 & 0 & 1 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 2 &  - 4 \\ 
 - 2 & 4 & 8 \\ 
 - 4 & 8 & 42 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 4 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 26 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 - 4 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 26 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 2 &  - 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 2 &  - 4 \\ 
 - 2 & 4 & 8 \\ 
 - 4 & 8 & 42 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Comment: Don't remember 18.06 lecture have teached this.:(